Retopology with vertex paint
I painted colour on my mesh with vertex paint. You are also able to colour the mesh with texture paint, but vertex paint appears easier.When I retopologize with BSurface, the mesh loses the vertex paint colour.  When I do retopology with quad remesher, the same happens. How do I do retopologize with BSurface or quad remesher and keep the vertex paint colour? I added the data transfer modifier. However colour, layer selection one choice is all layers. I see no way to switch it to the layer i transfer from. How do you choose a specific layer in colour, layer selection?

You can't. Vertex Paint assigns a color value to each vertex. When you quad-remesh an object, many of the vertices are removed and replaced, causing the loss of color data.
For instance, consider Bob here:
Bob sports a lovely mustache, along with a mask to conceal his true identity.

As you can see, Bob's face consists of many vertices, contributing to its detailed appearance.

Now, let's quad-remesh Bob, as he's too high poly and slowing down my computer. (Of course, this is just an example)

Oh no! Bob, what happened to your face?

Any vertices that aligned with the quad-remeshing process were retained, preserving their color data.

Ah nice!  I knew you could bake an image texture, or transfer the data some other external way, but I was unaware there was a modifier just for that.  Thanks!

Hi, aidan! It's a funny one, indeed.. I expect it will be absorbed into Geometry Nodes, eventually.

You can transfer Color attributes between objects with similar surfaces but different topology using the Data Transfer modifier:

Above,  a color attribute on vertices, called 'vc_smiley' is transferred to another of the same name from 'Icosphere_Tri' to a re-meshed version, using one of the available mapping methods:

If the modifier is applied, the color will be baked into the new topology.
